# Available ways to buy Bitcoin using leverage

Tags: trading

I have seen several exchanges that currently offer the ability to take BTC long positions with leverage.

BTC.sx - leverage directly from the BTC.sx, 0.85% / day
Bitfinex - leverage from other account holders, rates vary, but ~ 0.15-0.20% / day over the past several days

Are there other sites?  These margin rates that I have seen are quite high.  Does anyone know of sites that offer the ability to buy BTC with leverage, but at lower rates?

I'm a "buy and hold" investor, so I am okay with committing to specific / longer timeframes to hold the BTC.  Could that help?